# Get firebase values in loop

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having a problem with a Firebase search. Here's the scenario:
I have a list of objects (_list) and I get the 'id' of the object to search in Firebase.
In the search I want to return the value of the 'itemsSale' node and add it to another list.

[image]

The code:

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                final ArrayList<Integer> it = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                for (Product productAux : _list) {
                    productID = productAux.getId();
                    items = productAux.getUnit();
                    mDatabaseReference.child("bakeries").child(bakeryId).child("products").child(productID).
                            addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    int itemsSale = dataSnapshot.child("itensSale").getValue(Integer.class);
                                    it.add(itemsSale);
                                    Log.w(TAG, "itensSale: " + itemsSale);
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                    Log.w(TAG, "getUser:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
                                }
                            });
                }
                Log.w(TAG, "list size: " + it.size());
            }
```

However, it only enters once in the listening event, according to Log:

```
11-23 12:39:29.642 27722-27722/gregmachado.com.panappfirebase   
W/ProductCartActivity: list: 0
11-23 12:39:29.647 27722-27828/gregmachado.com.panappfirebase                                              
11-23 12:39:29.657 27722-27722/gregmachado.com.panappfirebase         W/ProductCartActivity: itensSale: 10
11-23 12:39:29.658 27722-27722/gregmachado.com.panappfirebase W/ProductCartActivity: itensSale: 10
11-23 12:39:29.659 27722-27722/gregmachado.com.panappfirebase W/ProductCartActivity: itensSale: 7
```

Comment: So what is the question? Is onDataChange only called once? Is the problem that your list size is wrong? (-->Asnyc operations, if these things are fetched from the network it obviously takes a bit until the results are loaded)

Comment: Exact, the onDataChange is called only once.

Comment: But in the log you attached it is called three times? Another idea: Why dont you just register a `ValueEventListener` on the `products` node and iterate through the childern to get the sale count?

Comment: I thought about it, but it's not all items in the node, just the ones that are in the list with the name '_list'.

Comment: Skip the child that are not in the list? Hm, but that could be also expensive if the table is big and the desired list is small. It depends on your usecase.

Comment: Oh. You said that is is called only once. addListenerForSingleValueEvent is actually the method to just query the data and not listen on followup updates. You should use addValueEventListener if you want the function to be called on updates.

Comment: Humm. I will try here

Comment: It did not work, just changing the addListenerForSingleValueEvent by addValueEventListener at least. It only takes the value of the latter and with very strange values.